# How to debug why server is blocking outsite requests

Tags: server, firewall

I install ufw, gufw & firestarter yesterday, but uninstalled them all today. Now, I find that I cannot access the server from outsite. When I could before. How can I debug whats blocking these?

Comment: Have you port forwarded your router?

Comment: @wojox, I think that shldn't be the prob as I am able to access the server ok b4 installing firewall etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the server? Although you have uninstalled the firewalls, their rules might still be active in the running kernel. (Run `sudo iptables -L` to list all active rules).

Answer (score 0):

I would run:

```
sudo ufw status
```

To see if you have the ports you want available allowed.

If you don't, I would recommend running something like:

```
sudo ufw allow 80
```

to allow people to access your server on port 80, as an example.

Edit: Ah, I missed that you had uninstalled them.